# React Conditional Rendering, avoid 0 evaluated to false/undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean, conditional-statements

I have checked the other Q/As. Mine is a bit different and I'm new to ReactJS.

Following code for setting const variable evaluates 0 as false/undefined
and value returned from myFunc is "" :

```
function formatAmount(x){
  if(x === undefined || x === null) return "";
  return(x.toLocaleString("en-US",{style: "currency", currency: "USD"}));
}
//When user.bill.amount == 0 this line evaluates it to false!!
const amount = user?.bill?.amount || user?.statement?.amount;

function myFunc(){
  return(formatAmount(amount));
}
```

I tried expanding it with a function and IF conditions but the value returned by myFunc is "$NaN":

```
const amount = () => {
  if(user?.bill?.amount || user?.bill?.amount === 0){
    return user?.bill?.amount;
  }
  if(user?.statement?.amount || user?.statement?.amount === 0){
    return user?.statement?.amount;
  }
}
```

Expected:

When user.bill.amount == 0, myFunc should return "$0.00"

Actual:

myFunc returns empty string when user.bill.amount == 0

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @Lenin Raj Rajasekaran, My question is how do I get myFunc to return "$0" when user.bill.amount == 0. I will edit the question, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: typo in `toLocalString` -> `.toLocaleString`

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is 0 is falsy so when using || operator 0 will evaluate to false.

`const amount = user?.bill?.amount || user?.statement?.amount;`

If your environment supports the nullish operator that would work here.

`const amount = user?.bill?.amount ?? user?.statement?.amount;`